# ASP.NET Dropdown list DataBind() taking extremly long

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, dropdown

Binding drop-down list with data from the database takes extremely long.

```
ddlTerminalType.DataSource = GetLeftoverTerminalTypes();
ddlTerminalType.DataBind();
ddlTerminalType_SelectedIndexChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
```

I have measured the time between commands and found out that the method `GetLeftoverTerminalTypes()` takes about 0.8 sec, meanwhile `ddlTerminalType.DataBind();` takes 5.74 sec alone.
The database returns 25 rows.

I guess, there will be no saving of time changing the DB structure, adding indexes and so on. All I need is to speed up the data binding. How can I make the DataBind part faster?

Comment: What does `GetLeftoverTerminalTypes` return? Maybe a query and not a collection which gets executed at `DataBind`. Use this code and compare: `ddlTerminalType.DataSource = GetLeftoverTerminalTypes().ToList();`. I guess now the first line takes 6 seconds.

Comment: Tim Schmelter GetLefroverTerminalTypes returns IEnumerable<TypedDataRow>

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't say anything about the real type. It could be a database query or it could be a "materialized" list. Have you done what i've said above?

Comment: @TimSchmelter i tried your advise, and the data bind isn't much faster.